# Simple blog using react redux react-router

Tags: react.js, url-routing, jsx, redux

I've implemented the logic of my app, but I'm not sure whether it appropriate way or not.

Task: create a react app using redux, react-router v4 which has a page with a form for adding new post and list of posts[image: page with form and list of posts]

and a page with a detail view of one of the posts[image: detail view of post]

I've added a unique id for each post with help of [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and pass id of each post to the corresponding link(react-router-dom link) in the post list

```
      <Link to={props.id} className='post__header'>{props.title}</Link>
```

When link is clicked it passes id to the DetailView component. DetailView component takes id and seek the post with the same id in the whole state then render the post

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

let DetailView = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  var currentPost = props.posts.find(post => post.id === props.match.params.id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{currentPost.topic}</h1>
      <p>{currentPost.text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;
};

DetailView = connect(mapStateToProps)(DetailView);

export default DetailView;
```

Github link: [https://github.com/LKTN/Branch/tree/dev](https://github.com/LKTN/Branch/tree/f7d78b65591497254464082f13e7c795878c7a70)

Answer (score 1):

### Misc

I'll start with these because to be able to use them in the next sections.

I personally prefer using `const`, but I won't get into the details, there has been enough debate in the media about it. In this case, I think that declaring the component with `let` is a bit misleading, because usually, you do this when expanding the API exported with the component, namely:

```js
let List = props => { ... };

List.Item = props => { ... };

export default List;
```

Which then gets used like this:

```js
const Showcase = () => (
    <List>
        <List.Item>First</List.Item>
        <List.Item>Second</List.Item>
        <List.Item>Third</List.Item>
    </List>
);
```

So, I would change the declaration of the component to:

```js
const DetailView = (props) => { ... }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DetailView);
```

#### Props

Destructuring props makes the code a bit more readable because from a glance you can see what the component expects:

```js
let DetailView = ({ posts, match }) => {
  var currentPost = posts.find(post => post.id === match.params.id);
}
```

#### `var`

`const` and `let` were introduced two fix a couple of gotchas that javascript had, mostly related to `var`. You shouldn't use `var` except in very special cases where you need its behavior (Take this with some salt, because I think that this behavior is confusing and using the alternatives improves the code).

You can read more about it [running a simple query](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+shouldn%27t+I+use+var+javascript&ia=web);

```js
const currentPost = posts.find(post => post.id === match.params.id);
```

### Redux

#### State to Props

I see you are mapping your whole `redux` state to your `props`. This is a bad practice because that will make your component re-render on every state change. Instead, [as recommended in the official docs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+shouldn%27t+I+use+var+javascript&ia=web), you should return only the slice of state that your component uses.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      props: state.props
});
```

#### Hooks

The [official docs for react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) recommend using hooks instead of the `connect` API. Changing your included code to use hooks would leave use with the following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const DetailView = ({ match }) => {
  const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts);
  const post = posts.find(post => post.id === match.params.id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.topic}</h1>
      <p>{post.text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DetailView;
```

### Router

I see you are expecting a `match` prop in your component. You can avoid that prop if you take advantage of the `useParams` hook that `react-router-dom` provides:

````js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const DetailView = () => {
  const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const post = posts.find(post => post.id === id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.topic}</h1>
      <p>{post.text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DetailView;
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks good after a quick skim. Just one point. I think this project could benefit from following the Container Component pattern so that the markup components don't directly depend on redux and are reusable.

Read more at https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005

Comment: This pattern of splitting components is no more the best way. Dan Abramov introduced this in this article [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) but he don't recommend it [anymore](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/802569801906475008).